# How to do a filter with varargs?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have a map of users and their favorite bands:

```
(def data
  {
    :David {"Tribalistas" 3.0
       "Daft Punk" 5.0
       "Lorde" 4.0
       "Fall Out Boy" 1.0}

    :Matt {"Imagine Dragons" 3.0
      "Daft Punk" 4.0
      "Lorde" 4.0
      "Fall Out Boy" 1.0}

    :Ben {"Kacey Musgraves" 4.0
     "Imagine Dragons" 3.0
     "Lorde" 3.0
     "Fall Out Boy" 1.0}
```

}
  )

and I need to filter the results that have two keys in common, in this case, band1 and band2

```
(defn common-ratings [band1 band2 ratings]
  (filter #(and ((second %) band1) ((second %) band2)) ratings))


(common-ratings "Daft Punk" "Lorde" data) ; should return David and Matt lines
```

but now, I need to transform the bands in a varargs, I tried to use something like:

```
apply and...
```

So I can use the function like this:

```
(common-ratings "Daft Punk" "Lorde" "Another band" "Another Band2" data)
```

but It does not work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you add your expected input and output and what you tried so far?

Comment: Every time I've wanted to apply and there has turned out to be a cleaner way to go about it. a sample call and result would help a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As has been said, `and` is a macro, so cannot be an argument to a
  function, `apply` or any other.
- The closest standard function to `and` is [`every?`](http://conj.io/store/v0/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0-alpha4/clj/clojure.core/every_QMARK/).

Since you have an unknown number of bands, pass them as a collection:

```
(defn common-ratings [bands ratings]
  (filter #(every? (val %) bands) ratings))
```

... where I've replaced `second` with [`val`](http://conj.io/store/v0/org.clojure/clojure/latest/clj/clojure.core/val/) to show that we're dealing with map entries.

For example,

```
(common-ratings ["Daft Punk" "Lorde"] data)
;([:David {"Tribalistas" 3.0, "Daft Punk" 5.0, "Lorde" 4.0, "Fall Out Boy" 1.0}] [:Matt {"Imagine Dragons" 3.0, "Daft Punk" 4.0, "Lorde" 4.0, "Fall Out Boy" 1.0}])
```

If you want to pass the `bands` as individual arguments, put them last to capture them as a *rest* argument:

```
(defn common-ratings [ratings & bands]
  ... )
```

... which you call like this:

```
(common-ratings data "Daft Punk" "Lorde")
```

... with the same effect as before.

Comment: `#((second r) %)` is just `(second r)`.

Comment: Thank you a lot guys, my final solution is:
   `(defn common-ratings [& bands]
      (filter #(every? (second %) bands) data))`

Comment: @renanreismartins Don't post an answer as a comment on someone else's answer. It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question, so that future readers will find it, but please do so as an answer rather than as a comment on someone else's answer.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to wrap `and` macro into function:

```
(defn and-fn [x y] (and x y))
```

Then you can use `reduce` instead of `apply` to achieve the same result:

```
(reduce and-fn [true true true false]) ; => false
```

For convenience, last reduce can be wrapped into another function:

```
(defn and-multi [& args]
  (reduce #(and %1 %2) true args)) ; initial value is needed for invocation with no args
```

Now it will behave very similar to normal `and` macro:

```
(and-multi) ; => true
(and-multi false true) ; => false
(apply and-multi [true true true]) ; => true
```

It will even have same behaviour with the evaluation of args:

```
(and false (range)) ; => false (despite of second param being infinite sequence)
(and-multi false (range)) ; => false
```

Comment: Sorry, but the function is receiving just x and y, how you can pass true true true false as parameter? thanks

Comment: @renanreismartins That's why `reduce` was used instead of `apply`. I've updated the answer with additional examples.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you a lot guys, my final solution is pretty close to @Thumbnail solution:

```
(defn common-ratings [& bands] (filter #(every? (second %) bands) data))
```